# show/hide datatable upon button click

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i have a requirement like i need to show/hide datatable upon button click . I tried implementing it , but its not working . below is the code .

please let me know if we can do with ajax . It is possible only if i set ajax to false .

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>hello world</title>
</h:head>


 <h:body>
<h:form>

    <p:outputPanel id="panel" rendered="#{bye1.showtable}">
        <p:dataTable value="#{bye1.carmodel}" var="cartypes">

            <p:column headerText="Model">
                <h:outputText value="#{cartypes.carname}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Location">
                <h:outputText value="#{cartypes.location}"></h:outputText>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Price">
                <h:outputText value="#{cartypes.rate}"></h:outputText>
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </p:outputPanel>
    <p:commandButton value="show" action="#{bye1.enabletable}" update="panel">
        </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>


package lifecycle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;


public class bye {

private String output;

private Boolean showtable;

private List<cars> carmodel;

public List<cars> getCarmodel() {
    System.out.println("cars populated...........");
    return carmodel;
}

@PostConstruct
public void bye1() {
    System.out.println("constructor called");
    carmodel = new ArrayList<cars>();
    output = "hai";
    carmodel.add(new cars("ford","chennai","4 laks"));
    carmodel.add(new cars("AUDI","chennai","44 laks"));
}

public String getOutput() {
    return output;
}

public Boolean getShowtable() {
    return showtable;
}

public String enabletable() {
    showtable = true;
    return "";
}

}
```

Any help ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `rendered="#{bye1.showtable}"` should be on the datatable, not the parent container

Comment: ya kolossus !! now its working !! i did that change

Answer (score 0):

Use an actionListener on your commandbutton instead of action.

"A return value of an empty string or the same view ID will also return to the same page, but recreate the view scope and thus destroy any currently active view scoped beans and, if applicable, recreate them:" 
[Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)

Also consider the use of Boolean vs boolean.

It also seems like your class is missing the @ManagedBean and scope annotations?

Comment: Thanks for ur comment Emil . I tried as you said , then again the same problem , its not getting displayed . changed Boolean to boolean , used actionlistener

Comment: is the method getting called? also what is bye1? isin't your bean called bye?

Comment: ya Emil , its getting called , i tried putting a sysout in the datatable getters and in showtable boolean variable . they are getting printed , once when i click the button .

Answer (score 0):

I think the `update="panel`" is not working properly, and the `panel` component is not getting updated. When you disable ajax, the whole page gets update, and maybe this is why the update works only with ajax="false".

Can you try this and tell me if it works now ? :

```
<p:commandButton value="show" actionListener="#{bye1.enabletable}" ajax="true" update=":#{p:component('panel')}">
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: thanks for ur response yanni, update="panel" is working and the component's getter gets called also (i checked with a sysout). i tried the solution that you gave too . the probelm is ,  in both the cases the getter of the datatable list gets called but the datatable is not getting displayed

Comment: What is the scope of your 'bye1' Class ?  can you also provide the code from method `enabletable` and the declaration + getter+ setter of 'showtable' ?  Have you tried debuggin on getShowtable() and check if it's returning the right value?

Comment: bye1 bean is session scoped . bean is in the question itself , you can scroll it down . the values are getting printed yanni upon the button click . but the table is not visible

Comment: again, can you check what 'getShowtable()' is a)called from 'rendered=..' b) what is it returning? Could it be it's always returning false?

Comment: hi yanni , im getting the following output upon clicking the commandbutton :                                                                showtable = true
showtable = true
showtable = true
showtable = true                                                         carname =ford
location :chennai
rate :4 laks
carname =AUDI
location :chennai
rate :44 laks

Comment: looks like it's returning the correct value. If you hit the button, then refresh your page (from browser), does the panel get rendered ?

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution .

i did a change like this

```
<p:outputPanel id="panel" >
        <p:dataTable value="#{bye1.carmodel}" var="cartypes"
            rendered="#{bye1.showtable}">
     ..............
       </p:dataatble>
 </p:outputPanel>
```

set the rendered attribute to the datatable rather to the outputpanel .